# Flink MapState Clear vs Remove

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink `MapState` has two methods, `clear()` and `remove(key)`. I have already set up queryable state for the map descriptor, when calling `remove(key)` in some ProcessFunction, I'm still able to query a key, i.e. the key is not yet removed from my map state, also checkpoint size keeps increasing. Do I need to call clear(),can someone explain what exactly both methods do?

Answer (score 0):

`remove(key)` removes the entry for that key from the map. `clear()` completely destroys the entire map.

`MapState`, alongside `ValueState` and `ListState`, is a kind of key-partitioned state, and is designed to be used with keyed streams (and broadcast streams). When you need to store a single value for each distinct key in the keyed stream, `ValueState` is appropriate. And when you want to store a hashmap for each distinct key, then use `MapState`. In other words, `ValueState` already gives you a distributed hashmap -- `MapState` is for cases where you need a distributed map where the values are themselves hashmaps. `remove` clears an entry in the inner map, while `clear` clears an entry in the outer map.